# Delete identical columns in SAS

Tags: sas, duplicates

I am working with a very large dataset containing the same columns several times, but with different column names (both character and numeric).
Does anyone know how to find and delete these identical columns?

**Example**

```
A    B      C     D     E    F    G
12   ab     12    ab    8    h   12
14   cd     14    cd    65   j   14
6    fs      6    fs    3    g    6
.     .      .     .    4    q    .
3     d      3     d    5    d    3
```

`A-G` are variable names, and I want to be able to see that `A`, `C` and `G` are identical and then remove all except one.
Also `B` and `D` are identical. I want to keep only one.

Is this even possible?

Comment: How big is very large? (number of rows and columns would be helpful)

Comment: Around 40,000 rows and 400 columns

Comment: Try to transpose numeric variables and character variables separately, then sort to delete duplicate records, transpose back and merge numeric variables with character variables.

Comment: Does order in the observations matter?  For numeric variables you can consider running a correlation matrix - anything with a correlation of 1 is likely to be a duplicate.

Comment: Do you have SAS/IML (and is this data sufficiently small you could use it in IML)?  I wonder if IML might allow a somewhat more efficient approach.

Comment: I'll try the transpose. 
The order of the observations does matter, yes. 
Correlation is not a bad idea! 
I do have SAS/IML 14.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example using technique proposed by Shenglin Chen in the comments.

```
data have ;
 input A B $ C D $ E F $ G ;
cards;
12 ab 12 ab 8 h 12
14 cd 14 cd 65 j 14
6 fs 6 fs 3 g 6
. . . . 4 q .
3 d 3 d 5 d 3
;;;;
```

Find the unique numeric columns.

```
proc transpose data=have out=tall_numbers ;
  var _numeric_;
run;
proc sort data=tall_numbers nodupkey out=keep_numbers(keep=_name_); 
  by col: ;
run;
```

Find the unique character columns.

```
proc transpose data=have out=tall_characters ;
  var _character_;
run;
proc sort data=tall_characters nodupkey out=keep_characters(keep=_name_); 
  by col: ;
run;
```

Get the combined list of columns.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select _name_ 
  into :keep_list separated by ' ' 
  from (select _name_ from keep_characters
  union select _name_ from keep_numbers)
  order by 1
  ;
quit;
```

Make new table with only the unique columns.

```
data want ; 
  set have ;
  keep &keep_list ;
run;
```

Comment: This works in my case, Tom. Thank you very much!
Do you have an idea to how it can be made possible to see which variables are the same? 
Using a simple 'proc compare' I can see which variables are deleted, but I can't figure out how to indicate which of the remaining variables the removed variables are identical to.
If this can be done, it would be a great help.

In the example this would correspond to an indication of A, C and G being the same variables, or C and G being removed because of A, or something like that. And the same for variables B and D.

Comment: Remove the NODUPKEY and the KEEP= option on the SORT and then use a data step.  You will need to know how many observations in your original dataset (easy to get). Let's call it &N.   `data groups; set tall_numbers; by col1-col&n ; if not (first.col&n and last.col&n);  group + first.col&n;  keep group _name_; run;`

Comment: Using the data 'keep_numbers' instead of 'tall_numbers', this works as it should. Thank you.

Comment: The extra data step does not work for the 40,000 rows. My computer can't handle this.

Comment: I found a reference that SAS/Share for version 8 could only support 32,767 variables.  Not sure if version 9.4 still has that limit, but 40,000 is a lot of variables to have!  I don't think this method is best for that many observations.